# How does MoneroClub work?

Tags: p2p-exchange, monero-club

How does [MoneroClub](https://www.moneroclub.com/) work? Is there a trust system that can be used to compare traders? Is escrow available? How does the site make money?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does MoneroClub work?

It basically is similiar to [LocalBitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/). However, MoneroClub works more like a bulletin board, where buyers and sellers can find, and subsequently contact, eachother. From MoneroClub's [website](https://www.moneroclub.com/intro/#intro):

> MoneroClub is localized peer to peer (P2P) exchange platform for Monero (XMR).
>
> Compared to typical exchanges, MoneroClub is decentralized. MoneroClub never has control of your transactions or funds. Instead, buyers and sellers work directly with each other.
>
> We recommend local cash transactions as the best way to prevent fraud and scams that often occur with PayPal, Western Union, or credit card transactions. However, it is possible to arrange any payment type with your correspondence.
>
> MoneroClub behaves similarly to a bulletin board. Buyers or sellers post advertisements describing the prices and quantities of XMR they desire to exchange, and interested parties can contact them directly to work out the details.
>
> We provide fixed or flexible pricing using a custom MoneroIndex (+/- any%) which removes dependencies on centralized exchanges for price information.
>
> Meet nice people in your region and let MoneroCommunity grow!

---

> Is there a trust system that can be used to compare traders?

At first glance, there does not seem to be some kind of trust system in place. Therefore, it is advised to be cautious when doing trades. Especially with a new trader.

---

> Is escrow available?

Given that is kind of a bulletin board, there seems no escrow available. However, the [core-team members](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people) are usually open to acting as escrow. You can contact them via their emails, or on IRC (#monero on Freenode).

---

> How does the site make money?

As far as I can see the site is basically a non-profit and was build to contribute to the Monero ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

As of today [MoneroClub](https://www.moneroclub.com/) appears to be offline. The closest alternatives are [MoneroForCash](https://moneroforcash.com/#) and [EasyMonero](https://www.easymonero.com/) which are listed with other [fiat purchase options here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/what-options-are-available-for-directly-buying-monero-with-fiat-currency)