# What options are available for directly buying Monero with fiat currency?

Tags: exchange, fiat, p2p-exchange

What are options available to convert fiat currencies into Monero directly, without having to go through a Bitcoin transit hoop first? I am not looking for a recommendation for a particular service, but a list of available options and supported currency types. I am looking for a list of both peer to peer and centralized exchanges that support fiat to Monero conversions.

Comment: Buy USDT then exchange for Monero at Polo

Comment: I think you mean where you can buy and sell fiat currency for monero. ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For direct purchase of Monero with fiat currencies there are now multiple options:

1. [Livecoin](https://www.livecoin.net/) - Online Exchange supporting [Wire transfer (SWIFT) and other options](https://www.livecoin.net/en/deposits-withdrawals)
2. [Coincut](http://coincut.com/) - Online Exchange allowing purchase by [GBP Bank transfer](http://blog.coincut.com/2016/08/17/buy-dash-ethereum-monero-gbp-wallets/)
3. <s>[Bitfinex](https://www.bitfinex.com/) - US dollar</s> [USD wire transfer disabled](https://www.bitfinex.com/posts/203)
4. [LiteBit](https://www.litebit.eu/) - Online Exchange supporting multiple fiat purchase options including [SEPA bankwire, GiroPay and SOFORT](https://www.litebit.eu/en/buy/monero)
5. [Orillia](http://orillia.be) - Purchase with SEPA
6. [AnycoinDirect](https://anycoindirect.eu/en/buy/monero) - Purchase with SEPA, Sofort, Trustpay, MyBank, IDEAL, Giropay, EPS or Bancontact/Mistercash
7. [MoneroForCash](https://moneroforcash.com/#) - Purchase with fiat locally P2P
8. [EasyMonero](https://www.easymonero.com/) - Purchase with fiat locally P2P
9. [Kraken](https://kraken.com) - Euro and US dollar
10. [LocalMonero.co](https://localmonero.co) - Any payment method that the community wishes to use, fiat or crypto, online or locally, a centralized P2P platform modeled after LocalBitcoins.com
11. [Poloniex](https://poloniex.com/) - Online Exchange with Credit card support and Wire Transfer for deposits and withdrawals

The options above meet your criteria for avoiding the Bitcoin transit hoop. Security, privacy and ease of use will vary.

[Bisq](https://bisq.network/) is a [P2P decentralized exchange](https://bisq.network/faq/) not mentioned above because it currently requires the use of Bitcoin as an intermediary currency when purchasing with fiat. There is hope that multisig support for Monero [now in development](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-high-is-multi-sig-on-the-list-of-development-priorities) will eventually enable direct fiat purchases.

Comment: Given that Monero currently does not have multisig integrated yet, you would have to buy Bitcoin with fiat first on Bitsquare. Subsequently, you are able to obtain Monero with the Bitcoin you have bought. This process also works the other way around. In essence there is no direct way on Bitsquare to buy Monero with fiat.

Comment: LiteBit.eu just added Monero too. litebit.eu/en/buy/monero

Comment: Didn't check all of them, but some of these options offer inacceptable spreads. Buying 14.86 XMR for 100 EUR at AnyCoinDirect, and selling them again for 89.96 EUR? No thanks. As long as the spreads  are like that, better buy Bitcoin with fiat and then XMR with Bitcoin.

Comment: monerodirect it's "offline"

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the list:

- https://monerodirect.com - buy Monero with Euro, GBP, or USD. (We can add other currencies if there's sufficient demand.)

Disclaimer: In addition to being a contributor to the Monero codebase, I am one of the directors of MoneroDirect.

Comment: This site can’t be reached.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: The site was shutdown recently because our payment provider OKPay.com was acquired by another company and they closed our account.

Answer (score 5):

**The Monero analog of LocalBitcoins.com**

https://localmonero.co

First on the market!

On LocalMonero.co you are dealing with humans. Unlike centralized cryptocurrency exchanges, you make a trade directly with another person. This makes the process lean and fast, as there is no corporate overhead. You get your Monero instantly. Also, LocalMonero.co can support every payment method its user community supports, making it possible for users without access to traditional banking to also be able to buy or sell Monero. For every transaction, LocalMonero.co offers escrow or transaction service to protect the buyer of Monero.

Full disclosure: LocalMonero staff here.

Answer (score 3):

updated answer (Sept 2016) since there are *new fiat <-> crypto exchanges* available:

- **buy/sell Monero with fiat using SEPA/PayPal**:

  1. http://orillia.be
  2. https://anycoindirect.eu/en
- **buy/sell Monero with Cash**:

  3. https://moneroforcash.com/#
  4. https://www.easymonero.com/