# How high is Multi-Sig on the list of development priorities?

Tags: multisig

.... and is there a rough ETA?  (  Soon..)

If this isn't being actively developed,  then is there things that need to be developed before this can happen?

Otherwise has there been any forum funding proposals concerning this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core contributor moneromooo [recently got funding](https://forum.getmonero.org/9/work-in-progress/86962/more-mooo-coding-goodness) for 450 hours of his work on Monero. However, there is no exact estimation:

> As before, I will not commit to any particular piece of work, but will
>   work on whatever needs doing to further Monero. Currently, my target
>   is rct verification performance, and then there is multisig, though I
>   will need help for someone who understands the crypto well to guide
>   me.

Browsing his [GitHub commits](https://github.com/moneromooo-monero) you can see, he is already working on RingCT Performance, but also on several other things, so I think Fluffypony's estimation of 12 to 18 for multisig to be rolled out is quite real.

Answer (score 3):

Though I can't speak for the devs on this, I can say that the RingCT multisig design is already well fleshed out and understood. As evidenced [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161023005318/https://shnoe.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/ring-multisignature/). With RingCT ready to be released, the work on integrating RingCT with multisig can begin at the very least.

Fluffypony has also said recently it will probably be rolled out in 12 to 18 months [see at 39:00](https://www.bitcoin.com/podcast/monero)

Answer (score 2):

Some changes have recently been made to the Github repo for Monero’s multisig development. Until recently, they had the “DO NOT MERGE” tag associated with them. That indicated the developers were far from having a working product. However, this tag was removed on or around 3rd November 2017, which seems to indicate a lot of progress has been made. Moreover, Moneromoo – the person responsible for the multisig implementation – has asked the community on IRC to test and review this implementation in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Multisig is in the current release (v0.12).