# What is the state of development of Multisig?

Tags: multisig

In this [thread](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-high-is-multi-sig-on-the-list-of-development-priorities) it was stated that after "RingCT ready to be released, the work on integrating RingCT with multisig can begin". Ring CT is now implemented in the testnet, so **I am wondering if there is anyone already working on coding it**. If so, I would be interested in learning more about it.

Also, mrl-008 didn't seem like a very polished paper, so I got the impression that there was a more detailed version of it somewhere or in the works. **Are there any follow up publications to that?**

Comment: Edited it, as requested. This is a follow up the referred post.