# Could a prediction market like Augur be built on top of Monero?

Tags: side-chain, smart-contracts

Are there any technical reasons preventing a decentralized prediction market like [Augur](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106367/augur) from eventually being built on top of Monero?

Besides [multisig](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-high-is-multi-sig-on-the-list-of-development-priorities) what other Monero development needs to be completed to more easily facilitate Monero smart contracts and sidechains?

Answer (score 1):

In the future, yes. Check out the Tari [announcement](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8lgvw4/introducing_tari_a_decentralised_assets_protocol/). This, alongside the ongoing work at the Monero Research Lab to bring daughter-chains to Monero, is a big step forwards towards Layer 2 capabilities.