# Exchange XMR for USD

Tags: exchange

I have recently started mining Monero on MinerGate. I created a Monero wallet on my phone and now want to convert the XMR I have mined into USD. I assume that this can be achieved by first converting to BTC and then to USD, but this incurs more transaction costs. Is there a way of safely and directly converting XMR to USD? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See question http://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1201. Some sites are only for buying but several of them also allow selling.

Answer (score 1):

You can sell for USD on Bitfinex or on bitsquare.io