# How do I sell Monero for USD if I start from the Monero in my wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, exchange, currency-conversion

Let's say I have my Monero wallet and there are some coins in it.  How would I go about getting USD for those coins?  I read about exchanges where one can buy and sell Monero on this thread -- [What options are available for directly buying Monero with fiat currency?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/what-options-are-available-for-directly-buying-monero-with-fiat-currency) , however after opening an account on the Livecoin exchange, it seems like the only way I can sell Monero is by first putting USD into the exchange, buying Monero, and then selling it at a later time.  How would I go about taking my existing Monero wallet and then exchanging that into USD?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a service like [LocalMonero](https://localmonero.co/) to sell the Monero directly to someone for cash if that is your preference.

Answer (score 1):

The exchange will provide a Monero address where you can send funds from your wallet. This address will appear if you click Balance and then scroll down to the Monero line of the "Crypto Balance" section. See this video for a demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__se5VGrgBM

The exchange will report that it is successfully holding an XMR balance for you. You can then instruct the exchange to sell those XMR for USD.

Lastly, you would withdraw the USD from the exchange to your USD bank account.

Comment: The exchange may also provide a *payment ID*, which is required to match the incoming XMR to the customer (unless the address is an *integrated address* or a customer-specific *subaddress*).