# What is the least expensive way to buy Monero with fiat?

Tags: transaction-fees, exchange, p2p-exchange, fiat, otc-trading

I'm looking to [buy](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1201/14165) monero using the Dollar Cost Averaging strategy where purchases are made for for relatively small amounts of fiat on a periodic schedule.

I'm a bit unfamiliar with the p2p approach but not opposed.  I'm looking for minimal friction with the best rate.  For an amazing rate I might jump through some hoops but nothing too extreme.

**What exchange or service might be suitable for Dollar Cost Average purchasing?**  Currently I'm finding that the cost to acquire monero with fiat from the major exchanges gives a very poor exchange rate to the point where DCA becomes less and less attractive and requiring a single, larger purchase.

Of course, crypto and fiat are both volatile.  Without resorting to extreme measures looking to get, generally, a good exchange rate **with the capability to send the monero to cold storage**.

If the hidden fees in the exchange rate are excessive that incentiveses large trades over small. Or, if the cost to transfer to cold storage is excessive that also would dis-incentivize smaller trades in favor of larger trades.

Comment: Monero now can be traded on Crypton exchange: https://crp.is/exchange/xmr_usdt The main its advantage is that it's decentralized, no KYC and is accessible from any part of the world. It means that no matter it's banned in your country - you can continue using it anonymously.

Comment: Seriously? How is this even possible? As far as I know, all exchanges have actually removed Monero. After the ban of this coin in most countries, having it in an exchange pair threatens the exchange with blocking.

Comment: I've heard on the Reddit that buying Litecoin with fiat and then Monero with Litecoin is the way to go. I don't have a source that this is optimal, though.